# How to perform efficient group by / sum aggregation on large tables in hsqldb?

Tags: sql, merge, hsqldb, database-performance

In my HSQL DB I have a large (>10M rows) cached table 'Products' where each Product has a 'groupId' and 'value' column. There is also an index on the groupId colum. In another cached table 'Groups' (also large, >1M rows) I need to store all aggregated values of all Products that belong to this group. So basically my query would look like this:

```
MERGE INTO Groups AS g USING (
    SELECT groupId, SUM(value) AS aggrValue
    FROM Products GROUP BY groupId
) AS sub
ON g.groupId = sub.groupId
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET g.value = sub.aggrValue
```

However, this does not work for large tables, because as stated in the [documentation](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/deployment-chapt.html#dec_mem_disk_use) under 'Temporary Memory Use During Operations', all rows affected by the update will be held in memory during the operation. I also tried to first write the aggregated values into a helper table with this query:

```
INSERT INTO HelperTable (groupId, value)
SELECT groupId, SUM(value)
FROM Products
GROUP BY groupId
```

but this also exceeds the available memory. I have already tried limiting the 
`hsqldb.result_max_memory_rows` setting to 100_000. What would be the preferred solution to aggregate the values and write them into the Groups table ? My main requirement is that the operation runs with constant memory regardless of the number of Products and Groups.

Comment: Have you tried splitting it into smaller batches? Like 10000 rows / insert?

Comment: No, but thats something I would like to try. Is it possible to do the group by on smaller batches (i.e. group by for first 10k, merge into Groups, then group by for next 10k ...)

Comment: `where id between 1 and 9999` first time, then `where id between 10000 and 19999` etc. Write a loop.

Comment: Ok it seems weird the database does not handle this by itself, but I will try.

Comment: It can't really make that decision. Sometimes atomicity is important, sometimes not.

Comment: I guess its true that the database can not split the given statement into multiple ones, but with my limited database knowledge I still do not understand why it cannot perform the group by/update operation without taking as much memory as it takes to load all updated rows into memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By design, HSQLDB performs some operations such as GROUP BY entirely in memory. It also stores the transaction history in memory until commit.

You can perform the operation in chunks, based on the `groupId` column. You need to commit after each chunk.

You can develop the update as a delta update. When new products are added, the sums of values for these product are added to the stored sums. Or when products are removed, the sums of values are subtracted from the stored sums.

Comment: How would I go about developing the delta update with performance in mind ? Using a database trigger ?

Comment: a database trigger is the best option

Comment: cant give you enough upvotes for keeping it up with hsqldb support